# I am using knockout with typescript where i am not able to fire or trigger window-resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, knockout.js, window-resize

**I don't want to use jquery**, as it's working with `$(window).resize(function () {` ... using custom handler.

If it is not possible without using jquery then please also comment here.

It is not showing me any error if code written as below, **resize event couldn't bind** :

my **app-root.cshtml**

```
<app-root></app-root>

<template id="app-root-template">
    <div data-bind="event: { resize: mainWindowResize }">
        <partial name="nav-menu/nav-menu" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <partial name="error-message/error-message" />
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

my **app-root-viewmodel.ts**

```
import ko from "knockout";
import { registerComponent } from "../../infrastructure/register-component";

/**
 * Application Root
 *   Provides an application root container for components
 */
class AppRootViewModel {
    constructor() {

        registerComponent("nav-menu");
        registerComponent("error-message");

}

    public mainWindowResize = () => {
        console.log("Window resize");
    }

}

export default {
    template: { element: "app-root-template" },
    viewModel: AppRootViewModel
};
```

Advance thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` tag doe's not support the window resize event. It is only supported on the `body` tag. (see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onresize.asp). You need to add the resize event on your window wich can be done without jquery:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', /* your function here */);
```

If you do this in your AppViewModel, this is against the MVVM pattern. Because you are using view logic in the ViewModel. Knockout provides a solution for this problem, named `bindingHandlers` or customBinding (see: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). With a `bindingHandler` you can register the the resize event on the `window` at your `div` element and call your function from it. Here is an example:

**BindingHandler:**

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.windowResize = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        const callback = valueAccessor();
        window.addEventListener('resize', callback);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', callback);
        });
    }
};
```

**Your HTML:**

```js
<app-root></app-root>

<template id="app-root-template">
    <div data-bind="windowResize: mainWindowResize">
        <partial name="nav-menu/nav-menu" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <partial name="error-message/error-message" />
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/FleMo/2h9s586k/2/

Edit: added a JSFiddle